# Issue with Tensorflow: model not learning anything, constant loss, unstable accuracy, validation accuracy exact 0

Tags: machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow2.0, image-classification

I am trying to train a small network for detecting JPEG artefacts, I have 7 classes with each 1k of the same images just with different level of artefacts.
My code looks like this:

```
import os

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

import pathlib

from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())

data_dir = "C:/Users/jilek/Downloads/AAT"
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir).with_suffix('')

image_count = len(list(data_dir.glob('*/*.jpg')))
print(image_count)

batch_size = 1
img_height = 1024
img_width = 1024

train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    seed=123,
    color_mode="grayscale",
    shuffle=True,
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="validation",
    seed=123,
    color_mode="grayscale",
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size)

class_names = train_ds.class_names
print(class_names)

for image_batch, labels_batch in train_ds:
    print(image_batch.shape)
    print(labels_batch.shape)
    break

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

data_augmentation = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.RandomFlip("horizontal",
                          input_shape=(img_height,
                                       img_width,
                                       1)),
        layers.RandomRotation(0.5),
        layers.RandomZoom(0.2),
    ]
)

train_ds = train_ds.shuffle(buffer_size=1000).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE) #.cache()
val_ds = val_ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE) #.cache()

num_classes = len(class_names)

model = Sequential([
  layers.Rescaling(1.0/255, input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 1)),
  layers.Conv2D(2, (4, 4), strides=(4, 4), padding='valid', dilation_rate=(1, 1), groups=1, input_shape=(1024, 1024, 1), activation='relu'),
  layers.Conv2D(4, (4, 4), strides=(4, 4), padding='valid', dilation_rate=(1, 1), groups=1, input_shape=(256, 256, 2), activation='relu'),
  layers.Conv2D(8, (4, 4), strides=(4, 4), padding='valid', dilation_rate=(1, 1), groups=1, input_shape=(64, 64, 4), activation='relu'),
  layers.Conv2D(16, (4, 4), strides=(4, 4), padding='valid', dilation_rate=(1, 1), groups=1, input_shape=(16, 16, 8), activation='relu'),
  layers.Flatten(),
  layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
model.save("./model/AAT")

epochs = 100
history = model.fit(
  train_ds,
  validation_data=val_ds,
  epochs=epochs
)

acc = history.history['accuracy']
val_acc = history.history['val_accuracy']

loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']

epochs_range = range(epochs)

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(epochs_range, acc, label='Training Accuracy')
plt.plot(epochs_range, val_acc, label='Validation Accuracy')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.title('Training and Validation Accuracy')

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(epochs_range, loss, label='Training Loss')
plt.plot(epochs_range, val_loss, label='Validation Loss')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.title('Training and Validation Loss')
plt.show()

test_dir = "C:/Users/jilek/Downloads/AAT_T/"
for file_name in os.listdir(test_dir):
    file_path = os.path.join(test_dir, file_name)
    img = tf.keras.utils.load_img(
        file_path, target_size=(img_height, img_width), color_mode="grayscale"
    )
    img_array = tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(img)
    img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0)  # Create a batch

    predictions = model.predict(img_array)
    score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])

    print(file_name)
    print(
        "This image most likely belongs to {} with a {:.2f} percent confidence."
        .format(class_names[np.argmax(score)], 100 * np.max(score))
    )
```

I tried playing with layers, optimizers even loss lossfunctions but all the time with the exact same result or error.
The log looks like this:

```
5768/5768 [==============================] - 40s 6ms/step - loss: 1.9472 - accuracy: 0.1954 - val_loss: 1.9467 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/100
5768/5768 [==============================] - 34s 6ms/step - loss: 1.9468 - accuracy: 0.0381 - val_loss: 1.9473 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/100
5768/5768 [==============================] - 35s 6ms/step - loss: 1.9468 - accuracy: 0.3358 - val_loss: 1.9469 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/100
5768/5768 [==============================] - 32s 5ms/step - loss: 1.9468 - accuracy: 0.1555 - val_loss: 1.9468 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/100
5768/5768 [==============================] - 32s 5ms/step - loss: 1.9468 - accuracy: 0.1130 - val_loss: 1.9466 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 6/100
5768/5768 [==============================] - 34s 6ms/step - loss: 1.9467 - accuracy: 0.2715 - val_loss: 1.9468 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 7/100
5768/5768 [==============================] - 31s 5ms/step - loss: 1.9469 - accuracy: 0.2384 - val_loss: 1.9471 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 8/100
5768/5768 [==============================] - 32s 5ms/step - loss: 1.9469 - accuracy: 0.0836 - val_loss: 1.9465 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

and after it finishes, here are tests on images that was not included in the dataset:

```
831180_005.jpg
This image most likely belongs to C060 with a 14.34 percent confidence.
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 17ms/step
831180_010.jpg
This image most likely belongs to C060 with a 14.34 percent confidence.
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step
831180_020.jpg
This image most likely belongs to C060 with a 14.34 percent confidence.
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 17ms/step
831180_040.jpg
This image most likely belongs to C060 with a 14.34 percent confidence.
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 21ms/step
831180_060.jpg
This image most likely belongs to C060 with a 14.34 percent confidence.
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step
831180_080.jpg
This image most likely belongs to C060 with a 14.34 percent confidence.
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 17ms/step
831180_100.jpg
This image most likely belongs to C060 with a 14.34 percent confidence.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the loss function you are using is inappropriate for your problem. From what I understand, your output is in a one-hot encoding format, not a sparse format. I believe a simple "CrossEntropyLoss" should work fine

Comment: I see, I thought so too but when I try it it always fails with ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 7) are incompatible

Comment: What exactly are you trying? Cause if the current output shape is (None, 7), you should change your loss function

Comment: Well I said it in the description above but I will try to explain better. I want to classify different levels of jpeg artefacts so I have 7 categories in dataset each by 1k images

Comment: I get that, but I mean, what have you tried todo that gave you the error that you said above

Comment: I just changed the loss to loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(), the rest is same as code above

Comment: what is the shape of your target in the training set? It should be (N, 7)

Comment: Hmm, not sure what target in training set you mean (I am sorry I am kinda new to ML), but num_classes is certainly 7 and there are 7 class_names in training dataset, element_specs is (TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1024, 1024, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))

Comment: As you can see [the shape of both y_pred and y_true are (batch_size, num_classes)](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy) as said by the documentation, I believe the y_true you have are single integer, so something like (batch_size, 1) and not one-hot encodding (batch_size, 7)

Comment: Well so I solved the error by adding label_mode='categorical', when loading the dataset. The accuracy is stabilised now and it seams it's actually increasing but validation accuracy is exact constant on 0.1311 now and finish testing images have still all the same metrics

Comment: I suggest you give a read to this article here https://towardsdatascience.com/categorical-encoding-using-label-encoding-and-one-hot-encoder-911ef77fb5bd

I believe you are having trouble understanding what your model is trying to predict and what you are giving as input prediction to your model

Comment: I was reading a lot of things, this one was among them too. I believe the training part is working somewhat now, but there must be some issue regarding the prediction part no way it can produce exact constant results, even if it wouldn't be learning properly

Comment: If you are using categorical data, your last layer should only make a single prediction, right? So if I say X[I] input gives me output y[i] = 5 (since you have 7 classes they go from 0 to 6), you last layer should be a single Dense neuron with an activation that allows it to go to values in this range, like 'relu' activation. I'm not sure if I understand the shape of your data and I don't know if you know that as well

Comment: Hmm, when I change last layer to layers.Dense(1, activation='relu') it fails with ValueError: Shapes (None, 7) and (None, 1) are incompatible. While I was reading stuff I discovered that I should use softmax for categorical and give it shape equal to number of categories. My data shape should be now exactly deffined by labels='inferred',label_mode='categorical',class_names=["C100", "C080", "C060", "C040", "C020", "C010", "C005"], unless this train_ds = train_ds.shuffle(buffer_size=1000).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE) is changing it somehow

Comment: Oh, well I think I solved it, the 3 Dense layers at end wasn't exactly optimal, so I deleted the Dense 16 and now it's learning normally